# Using php date format to another format?

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have date string "Tue, 2 October, 2018" and i need to convert another date format 2018-10-02. but it show 2017 . Why?

```
   <?php

   $checkin = "Tue, 2 October, 2018";    
   echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($checkin));

   //it show 2017-10-03 but i need 2018-10-02

   ?>
```

Comment: You would be better off using the createFromFormat function - see php docs http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your format is custom and not parsable by `strtotime`. You have to make it parsable. Here is how you can do it([DEMO](https://eval.in/918876)):

```
$checkin = "Tue, 2 October, 2018";    
$checkinDate = explode(',',$checkin);
$strDate = $checkinDate[1].$checkinDate[2];
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($strDate));
```

This code breaks the string at `,` and then joins the last 2 parts ignoring the day.

Or you can use `date_create_from_format()`, to parse this format, like([DEMO](https://eval.in/918880)):

```
$checkin = "Tue, 2 October, 2018";
$checkin = date_create_from_format('D, j F, Y', $checkin);
echo date_format($checkin, "Y-m-d");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your input format is wrong. Remove the second comma. It has to read

```
Tue, 2 October 2018
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove , comma after October and remove Tue,